# Vulkan: Memory leak when rendering

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, vulkan

I am doing a **simple program** with vulkan, just to get started. I am **clearing the back color**, that's it. The problem is that each frame the program allocates more and more memory and I have no clue where is coming from.

```
bool VulkanRenderer::Update()
{
    PrepareFrame(); ///--- < Commenting this
    SubmitFrame();  ///--- <  and this avoids memory leak
}//Update
```

This are the other two functions that when they are not called, the program's memory stays still.

```
void VulkanRenderer::PrepareFrame()
{
    ///--- Reset command buffers
    vkResetCommandPool(m_pDevice, m_pCoreCommandPool, VK_COMMAND_POOL_RESET_RELEASE_RESOURCES_BIT);

    VkResult iRes;
    // Get the index of the next available swapchain image:
    iRes=m_oSwapChain.AcquireNextImage(m_oSemaphorePresentReady, &m_uSwapChainImage);
    if(iRes!=VK_SUCCESS){
        CheckVulkanError(iRes);
    }

    ///---------------------------------
    /// Convert image to drawable
    ///---------------------------------
    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo oCmdBegin={};
    oCmdBegin.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;

    ///---------------------------------
    /// Prepare primary command buffer
    ///---------------------------------
    //vkFreeCommandBuffers(m_pDevice, m_pCoreCommandPool, 1, &m_oPrimaryCmd);
    //m_oPrimaryCmd=CreateCommandBuffer(VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY, true);
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(m_oPrimaryCmd, &oCmdBegin);

    {///--- Convert image to drawable
        VkImageMemoryBarrier postPresentBarrier={};
        postPresentBarrier.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        postPresentBarrier.srcAccessMask=VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
        postPresentBarrier.dstAccessMask=VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
        postPresentBarrier.oldLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
        postPresentBarrier.newLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
        postPresentBarrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex=VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        postPresentBarrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex=VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        postPresentBarrier.subresourceRange={VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1};
        postPresentBarrier.image=m_oSwapChain.images()[m_uSwapChainImage];
        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(m_oPrimaryCmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &postPresentBarrier);
    }

    {///--- Render pass
        VkClearValue clearValues[2];
        clearValues[0].color={{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f}};
        clearValues[1].depthStencil={1.0f, 0};

        VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo={};
        renderPassBeginInfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass=m_pRenderPass;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.x=0;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.y=0;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.width=m_uSwapchainWidth;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.height=m_uSwapchainHeight;
        renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount=2;
        renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues=clearValues;
        renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer=m_pFrameBuffers[m_uSwapChainImage];

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(m_oPrimaryCmd, &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS);
        vkCmdEndRenderPass(m_oPrimaryCmd);
    }
}//PrepareFrame
```

And

```
void VulkanRenderer::SubmitFrame()
{
    ///---------------------------------
    /// Executed submited secondary commands
    ///---------------------------------
    vkCmdExecuteCommands(m_oPrimaryCmd, 0, nullptr);
    ///---------------------------------
    /// Convert image to presentable
    ///---------------------------------
    {
        VkImageMemoryBarrier prePresentBarrier={};
        prePresentBarrier.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        prePresentBarrier.srcAccessMask=VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
        prePresentBarrier.dstAccessMask=VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
        prePresentBarrier.oldLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
        prePresentBarrier.newLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
        prePresentBarrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex=VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        prePresentBarrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex=VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        prePresentBarrier.subresourceRange={VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1};
        prePresentBarrier.image=m_oSwapChain.images()[m_uSwapChainImage];
        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(m_oPrimaryCmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &prePresentBarrier);
    }
    vkEndCommandBuffer(m_oPrimaryCmd);

    ///--- Submit
    VkPipelineStageFlags wait_dst_stage_mask=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    VkSubmitInfo submit_info={
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO,              // VkStructureType              sType
        nullptr,                                    // const void                  *pNext
        1,                                          // uint32_t                     waitSemaphoreCount
        &m_oSemaphorePresentReady,                  // const VkSemaphore           *pWaitSemaphores
        &wait_dst_stage_mask,                       // const VkPipelineStageFlags  *pWaitDstStageMask;
        1,                                          // uint32_t                     commandBufferCount
        &m_oPrimaryCmd,                             // const VkCommandBuffer       *pCommandBuffers
        1,                                          // uint32_t                     signalSemaphoreCount
        &m_oSemaphoreRenderComplete                 // const VkSemaphore           *pSignalSemaphores
    };
    vkQueueSubmit(m_pDeviceQueue, 1, &submit_info, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

    ///--- Present queue
    VkResult iRes;
    iRes=m_oSwapChain.QueuePresent(m_pDeviceQueue, m_uSwapChainImage, m_oSemaphoreRenderComplete);
    CheckVulkanError(iRes);

    ///--- Flush device
    vkQueueWaitIdle(m_pDeviceQueue);
}//SubmitFrame
```

Others:

```
VkResult VulkanSwapchain::AcquireNextImage(VkSemaphore oPresentCompleteSemaphore, uint32_t* pCurrentBuffer)
{
    ///---------------------------------
    /// Acquires next image in the swap chain
    ///---------------------------------
    if(!m_fpAcquireNextImageKHR){
        XLOG("%s:%d: m_fpAcquireNextImageKHR", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        return VkResult::VK_INCOMPLETE;
    }
    VkResult iRes=VkResult::VK_SUCCESS;
    iRes=m_fpAcquireNextImageKHR(m_pDevice, m_pSwapChain, UINT64_MAX, oPresentCompleteSemaphore, (VkFence)nullptr, pCurrentBuffer);
    return iRes;
}//AcquireNextImage
```

At the beginning I thought it was some Vulkan resource I was allocating and not deallocating, but this is what the Vulkan Debug Layer offers:

```
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 : Details of Memory Object list (of size 1 elements)
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 : =============================
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :     ===MemObjInfo at 0000000003BD6E58===
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :     Mem object: 0x3bd6ac0
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :     Ref Count: 1
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :     Mem Alloc info:
MEM(INFO):         sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO
MEM(INFO):         pNext = 0000000000000000
MEM(INFO):         allocationSize = 2621440
MEM(INFO):         memoryTypeIndex = 1

INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :     VK OBJECT Binding list of size 1 elements:
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :        VK OBJECT 62742624
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :     VK Command Buffer (CB) binding list of size 0 elements
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 : Details of CB list (of size 1 elements)
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 : ==================
INFORMATION: [MEM] Code 0 :     CB Info (0000000003BB4228) has CB 0000000003BB2AD0, fenceId a3, and fence 0
```

Every single frame there only seem to exists 2 internal resources.
I have also overloaded the new/new[]/delete/delete[] operators, and they are not called during the loop.

The examples I have been looking do almost the same, I have tried deleting and creating the primary command buffer each frame, still getting the same result.

**Not calling PrepareFrame() and SubmitFrame() fixes the problem. Why?**

Where could this allocation come from? How could I hunt down this kind of allocations?

Comment: Can you add some details on the operating system, graphics card and driver version used? It's possible that this is caused by an outdated driver.

Comment: You say that not calling both `PrepareFrame()` and `SubmitFrame()` fixes the problem - does this mean that if you call one, but not both, the problem still persists?

Comment: "*The problem is that each frame the program allocates more and more memory and I have no clue where is coming from.*" How much more, and how are you detecting this?

Comment: I don't see a call to 'vkCmdEndRenderPass'.

Comment: is the command pool created with the RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER bit?

Comment: @Sascha: I am currently using a NVIDIA Quadro K5200. But that leakage does not happen when running your examples. (By the way, they have been enormously useful). On a Windows 7 64-bit, driver version: 340.66

Comment: @zenzelezz One can't be called without the other. It will give me an error

Comment: @NicolBolas I am currently seeing it on the Task Manager. Like ~20 KBs per second.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes it is. Although removing it, and creating a new command buffer each frame does not remove the leak

Comment: @Orhun I have added vkCmdEndRenderPass(m_oPrimaryCmd); Just after the begin. Still having the leak

Comment: One big mistake I see is that you are not using fences to ensure the command buffer is no longer in use by the gpu before resetting it.

Comment: @Eder Since you refer to task manager, I assume this is a host memory. Use profiler to pinpoint the exact command that causes this. ; Also is this the same memory as shown in the layer log? What is memoryType==1 on your platform?

Comment: @Eder Remember Command pool can manage memory how it sees fit; does the memory usage really exceed reasonable bounds? ; BTW CP must be VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT even to be able to use re-begin. You should perhaps for your one single use buffer use pool without the RESET bit and reset the whole pool each update ; also from and to presentation Access should be MEMORY_READ.

Comment: @ratchetfreak For now at the end of each frame I am doing vkQueueWaitIdle. Doesn't this already waits for the command buffer to finish? I don't do vkQueueWaitIdle I receive the following message from Vulkan:  Resetting CB ... before it has completed. You must check CB flag before calling vkResetCommandBuffer()."

Comment: @krOoze I will try to pinpoint the allocation, any recommendations on memory profilers? My memory type 1 is VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT. It is not the same amount of memory as the displayed by vulkan. **It is 12kb every two frames**.

Comment: @krOoze I added the resetCommandPool  and the READ_BIT (leak persits). I think the memory exceeds reasonable bounds because the program goes from 20mb in memory to >100mb, so my guess is that there is some resource leaking, not just internal management of memory

Comment: @Eder: Can you upload the example or a vktrace of it somewhere?

Comment: @Eder In VS2015 compiled as Debug and profile in it should work(with per-line precission). Yeah 100 MB is too much for this. ;; Doesn't matter for this, but supposed to be `MEMORY_READ` not `ATTACHMENT_READ`. ;; `vkCmdExecuteCommands` can't be called with `0` ;; function loading should not be required for WSI ;; `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` does not block - that makes the semaphore useless I think ;; try experimentaly to destroy the Pool, if that releases the memory - that's really the only dynamic memory object I can see there.

Comment: I have found two sources of the leakage. One was a malloc without a free in the debug report callback, fixed. The second one is VK_LAYER_LUNARG_mem_tracker and VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation . **When I disable VK_LAYER_LUNARG_mem_tracker and VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation the leakage dissappears.** Code: http://expirebox.com/download/e6bd3cd23894f872790ae11f9175dc4c.html The architecture I am building it in is x64

Comment: @Eder Oh, that makes sense. Do you have the latest (17) SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As krOoze mentioned, try to update to the latest SDK, or (better) built the layers from source to always get the latest layers. Afaik there is still an open issue for the layers about correct memory checks, so they actually might be causing the memory leaks. Judging from the validation layer names in the source you uploaded you're not using the most recent ones, as e.g. the VK_LAYER_LUNARG_threading one has recently been renamed to VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading.

Using the current layers with my examples I can't reproduce any memory leaks.

But one thing that I noticed in your source:

```
    int iUsedLayers=0;
    const char* ppLayers[64]={};
    if(bExtraLayers){
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation";
#if VKMEMDBG
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_mem_tracker";
#endif
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_threading";
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker";
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_draw_state";
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_param_checker";
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_swapchain";
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_limits";
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image";
        ppLayers[iUsedLayers++]="VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects";
    }
```

Although it should do no harm, you actually add all the layers (except for the mem_tracker one depending on the define) twice. The [VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/e1d908ca8b5634cf3c48082c64b588fd8b823e2b/layers/README.md#standard-validation) meta layer already enables all available (base) validation layers in the correct order (which might not be the case with your order), so adding them one by one afterwards isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Updating the SDK and using just VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

another possible cause to a similiar bug is not calling:

```
vkDeviceWaitIdle ( Device );
```

inbetween renders/drawframe calls.  All submitted command buffers are added to a list that is only cleared from the:

```
vkQueueWaitIdle, vkDeviceWaitIdle and vkWaitForFences
```

calls. If you call one of these in the program, The uniform buffer code will call vkDeviceWaitIdle every frame through the copyBuffer call and it wont't have a leak from vkQueueSubmit() anymore.